# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError POI Workbook

Tags: java, exception, apache-poi, classnotfoundexception

when i try to launch JAR file im getting this exception, I've changed poi version about 4 times to try different versions but still JAR doesn't want to launch.
It's a test program because in other I couldn't launch JAR and I don't want to break anything in there.

I'm using JDK 17 and also tested it with JDK 13.

App:
package com;

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 7;
        System.out.println(x);

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.JAR</groupId>
    <artifactId>probaJar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    com.Main
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <!-- Configures the content of the created manifest -->
                <manifest>
                    <!-- Adds the classpath to the created manifest -->
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <!-- Specifies that all dependencies of our application are found -->
                    <!-- Configures the main class of the application -->
                    <mainClass>com.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>


    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Why you do not use last version of Apache POI? I tried your code and it woks.

Comment: Just downloaded the latest version and still im getting this message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
        at com.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 1 more

Comment: If you want to try gradle - this example works - https://github.com/pjfanning/poi-gradle-example

Comment: How are you "launching the JAR file"?  What IDE are you using?  At runtime, you need to give the running process a classpath that contains the JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

Reason why error like this occurs [on stack overfrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Maybe you're trying to launch wrong jar file.
There are two jar files created after compilation and packaging (full names omitted):

1. *.jar
2. *-jar-with-dependencies.jar

You must launch second one, because first one does not contain needed dependency classes.

Comment: When I launch the second one im getting this message
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setUseDefaultNamespace(boolean)'
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.<clinit>(SharedStringsTable.java:96)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.newDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:94)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.createRelationship(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:591) at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.createRelationship(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:500) at

Comment: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onWorkbookCreate(XSSFWorkbook.java:464) at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:255)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:249)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:237)
at com.Main.main(Main.java:14)

Comment: @PatrykŁasek 
Have you recompiled and repackaged whole project after updating version?
Did you updated all dependencies to newest versions or only one of them?
Can you update `pom.xml` in your question  ?

Comment: I' ve recompiled project and repacked it
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Comment: There are two ways to fix this. First one is to set all dependencies versions to 4.1.2, second one is to remove poi-ooxml-schemas from dependencies